# Jigsaw blade out of square - can I do anything?

Tags: powertools

I've just bought a MacAllister jigsaw - the cheapest of the cheap, as I only need it for one little job. I've quickly encountered a problem:

[image: jigsaw blade not seated on blade guide]

The receiver doesn't hold the blade straight, and as soon as I start the tool it immediately slips out of the blade guide. It loses most of its cutting power instantaneously and I presume this is also dangerous. Looking at the receiver it's a simple spring loaded buckle type device, and the surface it retains the blade against itself isn't square to the cutting axis.

Is there anything I can do, or is this just the price of buying a cheap tool?

Comment: Even a cheap tool should at least be straight.  If after reading the instructions again and finding no adjustment, replacement/maybe refund only option.

Comment: Confucius say: "The sweetness of a cheap price is soon replaced by the bitterness of having to use crap tools." If you buy decent tools you're more likely to use them again.

Comment: If return not possible, would at least take it apart.  Part curiously and part to see if it can be fixed(part in wrong place), would not put any money in it.

Comment: Check the blade clamp, that's where it's sitting at the wrong angle. Can't see enough detail of it to offer more. Worst comes to the worst, you could shim it… but it might just not be inserted correctly.

Comment: btw, if you intend to build a collection of cheapish power tools, look at something like Erbauer [seems to be B&Q exclusive] At least that way you only need one battery & charger, they're all interchangeable. Erbauer are also head & shoulders above MacAllister in terms of quality too, though not quite so bargain basement cheap, but you save 80 quid or more on the charging structure each time after the first.

Comment: @Tetsujin yep, the inner surface of the blade clamp isn't square to the cutting axis and the catch holds the T flat against it. I considered trying to shim it with something but that's just asking for it to fall out and suddenly slip while I'm using it. I actually got it from B&Q, and returned it just now. Replaced it with a Bosch that looks quite a bit better. I have had solid experience with Bosch tools generally and even though they're said to not be what they once were, I tend to trust them.

Comment: How is the wheel mounted to the tool ? usually there are two screws to slide it forward or back

Comment: Hah. You get what you paid for.   RealMen(TM) buy quality tools on the theory that someday, years from now, you'll need to use them again.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I've been trying to resist this logic, but it keeps being proved right over and over again! I have no doubt the Makita drill I bought on special offer a few years ago will outlive me.